# Java - decimal stays X.0 when calculating the average

Tags: java, loops, int, double, decimal

in this script I need to fil in a row of numbers and type -1 whenever I want to stop it. When it's stopped it should calculate and display the total of the numbers (sum), the amount of numbers filled in excluding -1(amount) and the average (avg). Whenever I type numbers like 10 and 20 it nicely shows that the average is 15. But when the decimals has to change, e.g. I type in 10 and 11 (so it has to show 10.5) it just shows 10.0 thus it's wrong. Why does the decimal stay on X.0 when the avg is a double? What do I do wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    int amount = 0;
    double avg = 0;

    while (true) {
       System.out.println("Type numbers: ");
       int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
       if (number == -1) {
          break;
       } else {
          amount++;
          sum = sum + number;           
       }  
   }
   avg = avg + sum / amount;

   System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
   System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
   System.out.println("How many numbers: " + amount);
   System.out.println("Average: " + avg);
}
```

Comment: Define 'decimal'. Do you mean (a) the radix (b) the decimal point (c) the decimal places (d) the digits? Hint: only (a) is correct; the others are just misuses of standard terminology. NB Java is not a scripting language and this is not a script.

Comment: sorry for that it was unclear, learned something new from ur post anyway ;)

Comment: Apology not necessary but the idea is to fix your post so people can tell what you're talking abut. Assuming meant an answer, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `avg = avg + sum / amount;` can be simplified to `avg = sum / amount;`.

The `sum / amount` part, however, will give you an `int` result, because both `sum` and `amount` and `int`s and by default the `/` operator produces an `int` result.

So you have to do a cast on (at least) one of the operands, i.e.:

```
avg = ((double) sum) / amount;
```

Comment: The expression is also incorrect. `average = sum/count,` by definition. The code only works because `average` was initialised to zero.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that was exactly what I needed. I wonder what this community has with salty downvoting though lol, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Convert int sum to float sum and int amount to float amount.
or

```
avg=((double)sum)/amount;
```